# Generating function and functional equation

Tags: combinatorics, probability-theory, generating-functions

Consider $P(a,b)$ to be a multivariate probability mass function with discrete support. In particular $a,b \in 0,1,2,3 ..$

Let me define a probability generating function as follows:

\begin{equation}
Q_a(z) = \sum_b z^b P(a,b)
\end{equation}

and suppose that such function satisfies this functional equation:
\begin{equation}
Q_a(z)[(z-1)\gamma\cdot a]=0
\end{equation}

where $\gamma \in R^+$.

Is there any method to try to approach this problem and hence compute $Q_a(z)$? Or is there any known literature on such functional equations?